# Webpack: 'bindings is not defined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

i'm building Application with nodejs (server) and reactjs (client)..
All fine, but recently i have some problem with webpack.. after that i run webpack i have error in a browser console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: bindings is not defined

I've got no idea about this issue.. any help ?

Here my webpack config:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './src/client/index.js'
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: './src/static/js/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
    }, {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: "json-loader"
    }],
    noParse: /lie\.js$|\/leveldown\//
  },
  node: {
    net: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    dns: 'empty'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/style.css', {
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/bindings$/, /^$/)
  ],
  externals: ["bindings"]
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `externals` is doing?

Comment: from webpack's documentation:

externals allows you to specify dependencies for your library that are not resolved by webpack, but become dependencies of the output. This means they are imported from the environment during runtime.

Comment: Right. Webpack will generate something like `module.exports = bindings;`. However, it seems `bindings` is not defined in the environment you are loading the code in, and that's why you get the error. So either you have forgotten to load the code that declares `bindings`, or `externals` is not what you want to use. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Were you able to get this working @CarmeloCatalfamo ? I have the same problem and I haven't been able to properly load bindings.